# How to access variables in Django url?

Tags: django

I have been trying to access the variables in the redirect I get from lyrebird API which is like:
http://website.com/auth/lyrebird#access_token=value1&token_type=bearer&state=value2
I am not able to access this access_token via GET or POST.
Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
I am sorry I must have done a deeper search before I posted the question. I found out that those # in the url  was for anchor tag and it never really got sent to the server. 
If anyone encounters the same problem in the future here is what I did:

var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); //Puts hash in variable, and removes the # character
window.location.replace('your django url?hash='+hash);

I sent a reply with this script.

Comment: That is not a proper URL. It should be `?`, not `#`.

Comment: No that's the url I saw in the browser, but those are anchor tags. Anyway I figured out how to get access to it :) for my specific need.

Answer (score 0):

Query string can be accessed via `request` object:

`request.GET.get('state')`

You can read about it in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#id1).

Answer (score 0):

Your url is not in proper format, this should be like this

```
http://website.com/auth/lyrebird?access_token=value1&token_type=bearer&state=value2
```

Then you can access your value like

```
 state_value = request.query_params.get('state', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get full path via `request.get_full_path()` and then parse it like this:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
url ='http://website.com/auth/lyrebird#access_token=value1&token_type=bearer&state=value2'
fragment = urlparse(url).fragment
parse_qs(fragment)
{'access_token': ['value1'], 'state': ['value2'], 'token_type': ['bearer']}
```